# Internal error including a EJS template in Express 2.5

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I have a node.js app that uses EJS as template engine and ExpressJS 2.5.8

I try to include a partial inside a ejs page in this way:

```
<%- partial('list') %>
```

I get a "500 Internal Error" . I've tried in many different ways , also using <% include list %> but i always get a 500 error. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: You should have more detail in your terminal or log file when the error occurs. Can you please include that?

Comment: No, here is what i get in terminal: node app.js
.....
Express server listening on port 3000, environment: development ...

GET / 500 67ms